# git command to add recent changes to last commit

Tags: git

Suppose I have made some changes after a given git commit. Is there any way to put this changes in the same previous commit? Right now what I do is to do an another commit and then do a git rebase -i HEAD~2 to merge both commits into one, but I would prefer a quicker way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have changes in your working-directory or stage, then you can use what Git calls ***amending***, and [`git-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) has an option for that.

Use `--amend` like this:

```
git commit --amend -a
```

You can reuse the previous commit message with:

```
git commit --amend -a --reuse-message=HEAD
```

**If you have multiple commits** that you want to quickly *squash* down into another commit then [`git-reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) can be a useful tool.

Let's say that you have a tree like this (and HEAD points to `C`):

```
A <- B <- C
```

If you want to quickly combine `B` and `C` into `A` to create a commit that contains the content of all three of those commits you could use `rebase` like you have in your question.

Or, you could use `reset` like this:

```
git reset --soft A
git commit --reuse-message=HEAD
```

The `--soft` option is used so that the content of the commits that are "reset-ed" over get put in your stage, and ready to be committed.
Of course you could give a unique commit message if you desired.

Note that both of these options are effectively rewriting your commit (just like a rebase would do) so there will be a new SHA. The old commit(s) is still available though and can be retrieved by using the reflog if needed.

[Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history) is a good link for more details about amending and rewriting history.
[Here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/527-squash-several-git-commits-into-a-single-commit) is a good article on squashing.

Comment: I think he is looking for a faster way to do something what the rebase does.

Comment: @AdrianKingLegaspi gotcha, I see that now. I updated my answer